# Vector image pixelated on the ImageView after changing build tools & gradle configuraiton?

Tags: android, gradle, svg

I have a vector image added in my project the view is as follows:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/display_id_tv"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_image" />
```

It working until now, I changed most of the Gradle dependencies from `compile` to `implementation` & changed `Gradle` version to 3.2.2. After these changes studio suggested changing build tools to `28.0.3` I made the change then build the application, No errors reported during the build process. But when the application was launched vector image appeared pixelated. What might have the build tool, grade changes having an effect on vector rendering? How do I resolve this?

***Update:***

As soon as I reverted my build tools to

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

& Support library versions to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

Vector image started showing up in good quality.

Comment: did you try using `app:srcCompat`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>` instead od `<ImageView>`. And as already suggested, use `srcCompat` instead of `source`

Comment: Novikcy Solution has not worked for me, Thanks for the response.

Comment: This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView